# Oracle SQL syntax between Standard/enterprise and Express

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have a question in different Oracle versions. In their download page, there is Standard/Enterprise, and there is Express. Other than performance and other infrastructure tools, do the two different versions support the same set of SQL script keywords? For example, if I generate DDL tables from standard, is there a chance it may not work on Express (data type, function name, etc may not be supported on Express)?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the PL/SQL API difference between Oracle Express Edition (XE) and Standard Edition (SE)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074791/what-is-the-pl-sql-api-difference-between-oracle-express-edition-xe-and-standar)

Comment: Disagree that the question is the same. One is SQL, the other PL/SQL. There would be resources that answer both questions but then the same could be said of any question which can be answered from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly they work, but with some restrictions.

For example, Standard and Express Edition don't support bitmap indexes or compressed tables. Express edition doesn't have Java but is otherwise close enough to Standard Edition. Express Edition is 10gR2, so any 11g (R1 or R2) stuff won't work.

Anything from a cheaper edition would work in a more expensive one.

Answer (score 1):

From the programmer's point of view, Express, Standard and Enterprise editions are the same. The only difference between them are in licensing and scalability.

See [this OraFAQ article](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_the_enterprise_standard_and_personal_editions_of_oracle) for the details.